# Jquery .change function not triggering

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering why doesn't this script works? I'm trying to get the value of the selected (one or many items) options in a SELECT MULTIPLE. What is missing?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('#ooo').change(function() {
    var foo = []; 

    $('#ooo :selected').each(function(i, selected){         
      foo += $(selected).valueOf(); 
    });

    alert(foo);
    //$("#test").text(str);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="test" id="ooo" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">test</option>
    <option value="2">bbbb</option>
    <option value="3">aaaa</option>
    <option value="4">xxx</option>
    <option value="5">zzz</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the code in the `$(document).ready()`.  the [jQuery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler will wait unitl the document elements are loaded, before binding the change handler to the element. Also wen using select multiple it will return an array of selected items.  Because of this you will want to run .each() on the val() of the select element.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#ooo').change(function() {
      var foo = 0;

      $.each($('#ooo').val(), function(i, selected) {         
        foo += parseInt(selected, 10);
      });

      alert(foo);
      //$("#test").text(str);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you it works. Now if my value is a number, how can I add those numbers? I tried `foo += parseInt(selected);` but it only seems to return me the first number... Why?

Comment: first dont ever forget the radix on `parseInt(selected, 10)` second what do you mean "it only seems to return me the first number?"  was only one number selected?

Comment: Isn't Radix optional? Anyway, even with radix=10 as value, it still only read the first item that is selected. In my example, if I select item 2 and 3, the total of my selection should be 5. Right now it's giving me 2. Any idea?

Comment: Radix is optional but will treat certain strings very strangely if you omit it.  I have updated my answer to handle the other issue as the selector inside the each statement was causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks John! I just added "var foo = 0;" instead of "var foo;" because it seems to treat it as a string. Now it works perfectly! (ps: i don't have privilege to edit your code, could you please make the change?) Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the `$(document).ready()` as your script comes before the select box. Also make sure to specify the script type, `<script type="javascript">`, some browsers doesn't like it when type is not properly identified.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this -

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#ooo').change(function() {
        alert($('#ooo').val());
    });
})
```

The jQuery `val` function will automatically return a comma delimited string of chosen value elements in a multiple select box. You should add the `$(document).ready` function to your code to ensure the `click` event can be bound successfully.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pNUQm/